# Add Swagger to .net 4.8 project and use AzureAD (Entra Id)

Tags: authentication, swagger, .net-4.8

I created a default  MVC Project using .Net 4.8 (.net Framework not .net Core)an added Entra Id (Azure AD ) to it.

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
  {
      OwinTokenAcquirerFactory factory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();
      app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(factory);
      factory.Build();

  }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "id of application",
    "Audience": "api://.....",
    "TenantId": "id of tennant"
  }
}
```

I can send authorized requests to that api with Postman.

I now want to authenticate with swagger. For that I added swagger 5.6

packages

```
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

I then wanted to show the "Authorize" button for swagger but its not showing up.

SwaggerConfig

```
  c.OAuth2("oauth2")
      .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
      .Flow("implicit")
      .AuthorizationUrl("http://myazureurl/api/oauth/dialog")
      //.TokenUrl("https://tempuri.org/token")
      .Scopes(scopes =>
      {
          scopes.Add("read", "Read access to protected resources");
          scopes.Add("write", "Write access to protected resources");
      });


 c.EnableOAuth2Support(
     clientId: "myclientid",
     clientSecret: null,
     realm: "myrealm",
     appName: "Swagger UI"

 );
```

[image]

How can I add authentication for Entra Id and make it work with Swagger?

**Edit**
After  cascadings remark I checked the generated swagger document, I updated the Flow to the correct value and set a token url it now looks pretty much the same like a swagger document I got from a working .net core project but there is still no button showing up

[image]

This is the working .net core configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question. As I understand it, the authorise button does not appear if something with the authentication is incorrect. My guess is that something is incorrect in the generated `securityDefinitions` section in the generated Swagger JSON. I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414465/how-adding-authorize-button-to-swagger-ui-in-java-ee-application) that is a bit similar. I assume that the .Token method is correctly configured in your code as well (as it is commented in your config here).

I would suggest that that you check the generated Swagger JSON to ensure the `securityDefinitions` and `security` sections are correctly formatted and contain the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

I think after installing required NuGet packages(`Swashbuckle` and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`) you should configure Azure AD authentication in your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"],
        Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}",
        RedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:RedirectUri"],
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            //you can add here any additional validation parameters if required
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            //you can add here any required event handlers
        }
    });

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            //you can add here any additional validation parameters if required
        }
    });
}
```

now try to update your Swagger configuration in the `ConfigureAuth` method of your `Startup.cs` by using the `c.OAuth2` method !

```
c.OAuth2("oauth2")
    .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
    .Flow("implicit")
    .AuthorizationUrl("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
    .Scopes(scopes =>
    {
        scopes.Add("api://<client-id>/access_as_user", "Access the API");
    });
```

Also add the Swagger middleware into `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.OAuthClientId("<client-id>");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

Ok again try to run your application and access the Swagger UI and if you done it correctly you should see an `Authorize` button.

Comment: The problem only exists in .net framework. Net Core works fine

Comment: @MathiasF so look for alternative authentication libraries or frameworks that are compatible with Swagger and .NET Framework, such as IdentityServe! I can explain more if you want.

Comment: @MathiasF I updated my answer plz check it out.